# How to create a set with the results of a function?

Tags: notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of elements and $f()$ be a function that according to a condition return one or more associations $(a_k,b_k)$ that comply that condition otherwise if there is not any association it returns $\emptyset$.

Which notation could I use to represent the set of all the possible associations returned by $f()$?

Thanks!

Comment: So, is your $f$ basically a *partial function* from $A$ to $B$, i.e. a function from a subset of $A$ to $B$?

Comment: The result of $f$ is a set of combinations $(a,b,c)$ where $c$ could be an extra attribute (the distance between $a$ and $b$ for example).